# How to install ColdFusion 9 in Windows 10 (IIS 10)

Tags: windows, iis, coldfusion

I'm wondering if anyone has ever figured out a way to install ColdFusion 9 in Windows 10 (IIS 10)? I understand CF 9 is not officially supported in Windows 10 / IIS 10, but I'm wondering if there is some clever way to make this work? Our ColdFusion production server is hosted by our ISP and we are unable to upgrade ColdFusion at this time, so I'm stuck with CF 9 for now. I would very much like to be able to continue to develop and test in the same version as our production server, and my new development machine is Windows 10.

I tried the CF 9 installer, chose the developer option, and got no errors until I got to the step where the installer wants to load the ColdFusion administrator page to complete the setup process where I promptly get a 404.3 not found error. I tried rebooting the machine, went to the CF admin and same results. After some further looking into this, I believe the issue was that the IIS handlers never got installed, so IIS did not know what to do with a CFM file. So even though the Admin files exist on the server, IIS doesn't know how to serve them to the browser.

When I try to use the Web Server Configuration Tool to set up IIS, it looks like it could work until I try to add all IIS websites and click OK at which point I get the error "Version 10.0 is installed. Supported versions are 4.x, 5.x, 6.x, 7.x". So might there be a way to fool the WSC Tool into thinking that IIS 10 is in fact IIS 7 or is that not going to help? I did take the step of adding the IIS 6-related management tools thinking that would allow the CF 9 installer to work with IIS 10 (this seemed to be necessary for IIS 7.x).

I have had a bit more luck running the 32-bit version of the installer, and trying to set it up with an Apache server instead of IIS, and it seemed to almost work but I am unable to create CF data sources using the ColdFusion admin, I get an error when I try to add a data source. It may have to do with some confusion about 32-bit versus 64-bit data sources, so I'll try to troubleshoot this approach some more.

Thanks in advance for any ideas/suggestions.

Comment: Why not install an Linux/Ubuntu on a partition?

Comment: See this - [Manually configuring Internet Information Services connector with ColdFusion](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/iis-configuration.html). While the article references IIS 7, the steps should still be the same.

Comment: I believe, connectors for CF9 doesn't work on IIS 10.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas/suggestions. Linux/Ubuntu is not an option for me as I only have the Windows installers (32-bit and 64-bit). I did try the manual IIS setup, but that didn't work either. At the end of the manual set up I get this error: Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not load type 'C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll'. At this point I have given up and will install ColdFusion 2016.